# Selecting and changing an appended HTML input tag in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, append

I have an issue I cannot solve through research/Google.  I successfully appended the following input boxes to my HTML/JQuery project.  They all appear as intended on the web page.

```
for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  var id = myUniqueIDs[i];
  $("#targetedDiv").append(myUniqueIDs[i] + ': <input id = "' + id + '" type = "text" class = "findOutputs" readonly/>');
}
```

Later on in my code, after some user interaction, I try to write some info into the input boxes.  They cannot be written into by the user (they are readonly).  I know I can write into a read only input box via Jquery because it is done elsewhere in my project.  However it just isn't working.

```
for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  var y = getY(); // the returned variable is confirmed correct via debugging
  var id = myUniqueIDs[i]; // again, confirmed correct
  $('#' + id).val(y); // does not work
}
```

When I put `var test = $("#targetedDiv").html();` in my code it I can see that test is

```
uniqueID1: <input id="uniqueID1" class="findOutputs" readonly="" type="text">
uniqueID2: <input id="uniqueID2" class="findOutputs" readonly="" type="text">
uniqueID3: <input id="uniqueID3" class="findOutputs" readonly="" type="text">
```

So I honestly have no idea what the issue is. Is there something illegal with `$('#' + id).val(y);`?

Can you not select an appended tag in Jquery?  Can someone point out what I am missing here?

The issue is definitely with the selection because I tried `var test = $("#targetedDiv").html();` AFTER the part where I change the value and there is no difference on the variable test as when it was done before the second loop, so `$('#' + id).val(y);` (or other suggestions in answers) is having no effect.

Comment: Perfectly legal to concat an ID like you're doing - can you repro this behavior in a fiddle?

Comment: Once an element is in the DOM, you can select it just like elements that were created statically.

Comment: I could try to recreate this in a fiddle, but I won't be able to do that for a couple hours.  I am also (admittedly) not the best programmer (I've been programming less than a year), and I've never used fiddle before so I don't know how well that will go ;).  I appreciate those who have read the question.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a problem with the function `getY()`. I tried the code with a value, instead of the function and it works. see here: http://jsbin.com/pacevudigami/1/edit

Comment: There is definitely no issue with the getY() function.

Comment: Does it mean anything that the second for loop occurs inside a $("#inputField").change function?

Comment: If the ids contain special characters you'll have to escape them.

Comment: Musa, I suggest you put an answer in so I can check it, because you have solved the problem!  Because the ID variables are coming from the server side, I forgot to make sure there were no spaces in them.  Thank you!  Man I feel silly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Musa answered the question in the comments.
"If the ids contain special characters you'll have to escape them."
My (real) IDs contained a space.